# How to change anaconda start folder

Tags: python, anaconda, directory

Recently,I reinstalled the Anaconda distribution,but the start folder like the image below changed to "E:\Users\User\Documents".
How should I change it back to "C:\Users\User"?

And if the path is "E:\Users\User\Documents", does it mean I run the Anaconda by "E:\" ? Because my "C:\" is run by SSD,"D:\" is run by HDD.

Thx

[image: how to change E:\Users\User\Documents to C:\Users\User]

[Cannot find "Anaconda" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOtF1.png)
[Changed the start in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxain.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows I can help you with a regedit that adds a button to shell (when you right click a folder). That way you can open it anywhere.

Example images:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

**Elaborating further**

We could create the .reg file doing this:

```
import os
user = os.environ.get('USERNAME')

with open("additems.reg",'w') as f:
        f.write(r'''Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Anaconda]
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
"Position"="Bottom"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Anaconda\command]
@="cmd.exe /K \"C:\\Users\\{0}\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat\" C:\\Users\\{0}\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3"'''.format(user))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I cannot find the "Anaconda" folder in "shell" folder. The image was posted above.

Comment: the image title was Cannot find "Anaconda" folder

Comment: @BrandonFang I just posted some examples. There are a few steps to create that but one effective way is by creating a reg file. Just make sure that the paths are correct.